# custom row layout in list view android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am making a listview with a custom row layout . When i change the contents of the row on item click listener then change other item when scroll down . how to get ride of this problem ?

actually i want to add edit and deletion functionality in list view. on item click i want to show edit and delete button in that row which is clicked but the changes are also applied to the other row when scroll down . for example if click the item at row number 1 then the edit and delete button are also show in row 7. and also every time the shows button in the row which is after 7 items .

how can i done this job ??

Comment: Code code code, without some code probably know one can solve your problem.

Comment: i don't addthe code because that is not a problem of code . That is dew to the scroll. the when list is scrolled it revise the layout that why it repeats the upper layout

Comment: This is a code problem. If you don't add some code this question will very probably be closed.

Comment: i simply shows these button in listview1.onItemClickListener .
and button are declared from View returned in methode.

Comment: I read your questions five times... I really can't understand what did you write, sorry.

Comment: simply i want to show two hidden button in custom row layout on a button click which is in that row